# If it is incorrect 3 times... Game over

Tags: javascript

I am doing a trivia (with an API) and the third wrong answer the game over, but there I only have it written with only one wrong answer.
Do you know how it can be done with three incorrect answers?

```
choices.forEach(choice => {
    choice.addEventListener("click", e => {
      if (!acceptingAnswers) return;

      acceptingAnswers = false;
      const selectedChoice = e.target;
      const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset["number"];

      const classToApply =
        selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? "correct" : "incorrect";

      if (classToApply === "correct") {
        incrementScore(CORRECT_BONUS);
      } else if (classToApply === "incorrect") {
        incrementScore( INCORRECT_BONUS);
      }
```

**//If it is incorrect 3 times... Game over**

```
if ((classToApply === "incorrect")){
        return window.location.assign("/html/end.html");
      }

      selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply);

      setTimeout(() => {
        selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply);
        getNewQuestion();
       }, 1000);
    });
  });

  incrementScore = num => {
    score += num;
    scoreText.innerText = score;
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to keep a count of how many incorrect and act accordingly.

```
let wrongAnswers = 0;
choices.forEach(choice => {
choice.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (!acceptingAnswers) return;

  acceptingAnswers = false;
  const selectedChoice = e.target;
  const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset["number"];

  const classToApply =
    selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? "correct" : "incorrect";

  if (classToApply === "correct") {
    incrementScore(CORRECT_BONUS);
  } else if (classToApply === "incorrect") {

    incrementScore( INCORRECT_BONUS);
    wrong++;
    if(wrong >= 3){
       window.location.assign("/html/end.html");
    }
  }
```